# What is the difference between deployment and merge in github

Tags: github, deployment, pull-request

I'm working on a project and a new user of Github I'm not sure I understand the difference between merging and deployment.
Working with pull requests, sometimes I see:
[image: deploy and not merge]

The PR is still open.

Where as sometimes I see some pull requests not deployed and not merged:
[image]

Obviously I see the difference, when it's deployed I can see the change on the website. And when I'm sure the result is good I can merge the request.
The question is, how can I deploy a PR without the merging, is there a command?

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know this also

Answer (score 0):

When you say merge, you are merging the code to the branches and when you say deploy, you are deploying the code to the work environment (for eg., sandbox).